# Return response.data not Promise result in Javascipt

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to use axios for API requests. My code looks like this.

```
  const trigger = async () => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      if (value.name == source){
        return await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/"+value.someid).then(
          (response) => response.data
        );
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(trigger())
```

Here, I'm trying to hit an endpoint for some id. And I got the promise result in console.log.
I thought I should get the `response.data` not the entire promise. Why is this?

### Edit

Still getting the entire Promise with this code :(

```
  const trigger = async () => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      if (value.name == source){
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/"+value.someid);
        return response.data;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(trigger())
```

Comment: `trigger().then(data => console.log(data))`. All promises have to be thenned or awaited if you want their result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still getting the same result with above code :(

Comment: your `trigger` function, by definition, returns a Promise - that's what `async` functions ALWAYS return, it's in the description - use await or .then on `trigger()`

Answer (score 2):

In your question you are logging out trigger function without using await keyword, So the expected output for **console.log(trigger())** would be a promise.

**SOLUTION**

You will need to **await** the trigger function call, but in order to use the await call you will need to it be **inside an async function**, since **top level await** is not yet supported.you will have to wrap the call inside an async function and use await to resolve the promise.

check the below code, I have used an Starwars API for simulating the question.

```
const trigger = async () => {
let response;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) {
  if (value === 2) {
    console.log('passed');
    response = await axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${value}`);
  }
 }
 return response;
};
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await trigger();
  console.log(response);
};
```

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3jhu1x?file=src/App.js) is the sample react code in stack blitz

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await trigger()` or use `.then` to wait for the Promise to resolve. Also, I would recommend using either async/await or Promise.then() and not combining them:

```
const response =  await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/"+value.someid);
return response.data;
```

or

```
return axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/"+value.someid).then(
  (response) => response.data
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! But I'm still getting the same result. I added the edited code above. What's still wrong there?

Comment: You have to `await` your call to trigger: `console.log(await trigger());`

Comment: Thanks again! I tried but I get this error `Unexpected reserved word 'await' `

Comment: use `await` in an `async` function ... or use `trigger.then(result => console.log(result))` - because there is no way to "use" an asynchronous result synchronously

Comment: @Bravo, Thanks! The new code under `Edit` uses await in the function (Am I still doing something wrong there?). I tried `.then` method but still no luck..

Comment: you're probably doing something else wrong - add the current code **to the question** - don't discuss it under this answer